# how do I create invisible regions on a user control

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I would like to make my user control have invisible areas like the areas that surround a circle or an irregular shape. I have seen this done with a system.windows.form but not with a system.windows.form.usercontrol. How is this done?

.net 2.0,c#,winform

Comment: Making something invisible is easy, just don't draw it.  Do you actually mean "transparent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the control's [Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region(v=VS.90).aspx) to an irregular [GraphicsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx). Here's an article that shows [how to create irregular shaped menuitems](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0260__GUI/IrregularshapeofButton.htm)